# Aggregation of aggregation on Google Bigquery

Tags: struct, nested, google-bigquery, aggregation

My Data looks like this

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('2019-10-26' as date,'1.8025137' AS article_id, 'Digital Paying' as user_type,'open' as openmode, '123' as uid),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Digital Paying','close', '523'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Anonymous','open', '321'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Registered','close', '231'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Registered','open', '431'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Digital Paying','close', '132'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Anonymous','close', '111')
  ])  
),
-- first level of aggregation, prepare for fine tuning
date_article as (
  SELECT 
    date,
    article_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(struct(user_type,openmode, uid)) AS ut
  FROM test
  GROUP BY 1,2
)

 (SELECT 
  date,
  article_id,
  -- feed sub-query output into an array "action"
  array(SELECT AS STRUCT 
     user_type as user_type, -- re-group data within the array by field "action"
     array_agg(struct(openmode as openmode,uid as uid) ) op 
   FROM UNNEST(ut)
   GROUP BY 1
   ) as user_types
FROM date_article)
```

My goal is to aggregate the user_types.op.openmode and user_types.op.uid by 
user_types.user_type without create any duplicates as :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think  you are looking for below

```
#standardSQL
WITH test AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('2019-10-26' AS DATE,'1.8025137' AS article_id, 'Digital Paying' AS user_type,'open' AS openmode, '123' AS uid),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Digital Paying','close', '523'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Anonymous','open', '321'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Registered','close', '231'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Registered','open', '431'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Digital Paying','close', '132'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Anonymous','close', '111')
  ])  
), users_agg AS (
  SELECT DATE, article_id, user_type, openmode, COUNT(DISTINCT uid) AS uids 
  FROM test GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
), modes_agg AS (
  SELECT DATE, article_id, user_type, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(openmode, uids)) AS modes
  FROM users_agg GROUP BY 1,2,3
), types_agg AS (
  SELECT DATE, article_id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(user_type, modes)) types
  FROM modes_agg GROUP BY 1,2
), article_agg AS (
  SELECT DATE, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(article_id, types)) articles
  FROM types_agg GROUP BY 1
) 
SELECT *
FROM article_agg
```

with result

[image]

Comment: waited to your answer :)

Comment: How this answer would change if there are like 30 columns and need to use all of them? I'm facing the same problem and this is the same desired output, but with more columns.

Answer (score 0):

You were making it a bit more complicated than necessary.  If possible, do your 'normal' SQL first and then format into arrays/structs afterwards.

```
WITH test AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT('2019-10-26' as date,'1.8025137' AS article_id, 'Digital Paying' as user_type,'open' as openmode, '123' as uid),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Digital Paying','close', '523'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Anonymous','open', '321'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Registered','close', '231'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Registered','open', '431'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Digital Paying','close', '132'),
    ('2019-10-26','1.8025137' , 'Anonymous','close', '111')
  ])  
),
agg as (
  select
    date,
    article_id,
    user_type,
    openmode,
    count(distinct uid) as uids
  from test
  group by 1,2,3,4
),
final as (
  select
    date,
    article_id,
    user_type,
    array_agg(struct(openmode, uids)) as subfields
  from agg
  group by 1,2,3
)
select * from final
```