# Is it possible to calculate aggregate of an aggregate in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, is it possible to calculate aggregate of aggregate without using sub-queries? For example, Median of Max per user can be achieved by:

```
SELECT PERCENTILE_CONT(x, 0.5) FROM
(SELECT user_id, MAX(property) x FROM table GROUP BY 1)
```

If possible I would like to reduce this to

```
SELECT some_function FROM table
```

Reason for this request is to be able to integrate such queries into our BI tools. Our tools assume the source table is a fixed table and allow us grouping or filtering with dimensions. The initial approach requires a different sub-query definition for every filter and group by(ie. median of max per user per country).

Comment: Have you looked at UDFs (user defined functions)? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions

Comment: Hi OP! Did the UDF, as suggested by @Mike Karp, already worked for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I don't think UDF solves the issue here as the purpose is to be able to group by and filter in the base query. I need to function to work on queries such as `SELECT country, median_of_max_per_user FROM table WHERE time > x GROUP BY 1` for any grouping and filtering. As far as I understand if I go the UDF route then it won't support such queries.

Comment: You may try to refer to this similar SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58591941/aggregation-of-aggregation-on-google-bigquery and use your intended data to meet your expected output.